# python nested conditionals homework

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am learning conditionals in python and got stuck on one exercise which is very simple but I can't get it right. I am hoping someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

I need to write a code that will print either `"You may see that movie!"` or `"You may not see that movie!"` based on the criteria below. However, I am not allowed to use `and` operator anywhere in this code.

- Any child can see a G-rated movie.
- To see a PG-rated movie, your child must be 8 or older.
- To see a PG-13-rated movie, your child must be 13 or older.
- To see an R-rated movie, your child must be 17 or older.
- Your child may never see an NC-17 movie.

My code:

```
if rating == "G":
    print("You may see that movie!")

elif rating == "PG":
    if age >= 8:
        print("You may see that movie!") 

    elif rating == "PG-13":
        if age >= 13:
            print("You may see that movie!") 

        elif rating == "R":
            if age >= 17:
                print("You may see that movie!")        
        else:
            print("You may not see that movie!")
```

Answer (score 1):

First determine what the rating of the movie is:

```
if rating == "G":
    # the movie has a rating of "G"
    # check age conditions for a movie with rating of "G"

elif rating == "PG":
    # the movie has a rating of "PG"
    # check age conditions for a movie with rating of "PG"

elif rating == "PG-13":
    # the movie has a rating of "PG-13"
    # check age conditions for a movie with rating of "PG-13"

elif rating == "R":
    # the movie has a rating of "R"
    # check age conditions for a movie with rating of "R"

else:
    # the movie has a rating of "NC-17"
    # check age conditions for a movie with rating of "NC-17"
```

Note that all the `elif`s and the `else` are aligned with the first `if` and are not indented because they all belong to that `if` (i.e. they are in the same block of code). This means that the conditions are checked from top to bottom until one of the conditions holds (and none of the other conditions below that are checked anymore). Then all the indented codes below that condition (i.e. code block) is executed. In case that none of the conditions holds, then the code in the `else` block is executed.

Now we only need to fill each of those `if/elif/else` blocks with `if/else` blocks to check the age restrictions:

```
if rating == "G":
    # there is no condition to see a "G" rated movie
    print("You may see that movie!") 

elif rating == "PG":
    # you must be 8 years or older to see a "PG" rated movie
    if age >= 8:
        print("You may see that movie!")
    else:
        print("You may not see that movie!")

elif rating == "PG-13":
    # you must be 13 years or older to see a "PG-13" rated movie
    if age >= 13:
        print("You may see that movie!")
    else:
        print("You may not see that movie!")

elif rating == "R":
    # you must be 17 years or older to see a "R" rated movie
    if age >= 17:
        print("You may see that movie!")
    else:
        print("You may not see that movie!")

else:
    # it is a "NC-17" rated movie; you are not allowed to see this movie at all
    print("You may not see that movie!")
```

**Don't forget that indentation is very important in Python. Each indentation level defines a block of code and therefore determines which blocks are under which blocks (i.e. nested blocks). [Here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3) is a short tutorial that explains this.**

Comment: Thank you very much! This is helpful and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

To simplify today's answer, you may use a dictionnary:

```
min_ages = {
    'G': 0,
    'PG': 8,
    'PG-13': 13,
    'R': 17,    
}

min_age = min_ages.get(rating)
if min_age is None:
    # it is a "NC-17" rated movie; you are not allowed to see this movie at all
    print("You may not see that movie!")
else:
    if age >= min_age:
        print("You may see that movie!")
    else:
        print("You may not see that movie!")
```